# Get field/column from related table and filter it

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filters

I have models:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    pass


class RegionAnimal(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(...)
    animal = models.ForeignKey(Animal, ..., related_name="region_animals")
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, ...)


class LocationAnimal(models.Model):
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    animal = models.ForeignKey(Animal, ..., related_name="location_animals")
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, ...)
```

I have a `RegionAnimalViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, GenericViewSet)` where I can filter `QuerySet` with `animal` and `region` fields using `django_filters`. I want to add to response `count` field from `LocationAnimal` using `location` field. How can I achieve this?

So, my request will be like:

```
{{ some_endpoint }}/?region=1&location=2
```

What I expect:

```
[
    ...,
    {
        "id": 1,
        "region": {
            # region details
        },
        "animal": {
            # animal details
        },
        "price": 100, # animal price for particular region
        "count": 123, # animal count for particular location 
   },
   ...
]
```

FYI: Some `Region`s have some `Location`s. `Animal`'s price should be general for the whole `Region`. And `Animal`'s count are different for the different `Location`s.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: But there can be *multiple* `LocationAnimal`s for the same `Animal`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yeah, I want to filter it by sending `location` to get only related `LocationAnimal` count

Comment: But even for the same animal and the same location there can be *multiple* `LocationAnimal`s. It is also not clear to me how a `Location` maps to a `Region` here.

Comment: In your context what exactly is a `Region` and a `Location`? Your use case makes it feel like your models are not normalized.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I use `unique_together = ("location", "animal")` for `LocationAnimal`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat regions have some locations.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily have `count` in your DRF responses using pagination classes.
And it also works with `django_filters` perfectly.

Just checkout the [DRF Pagination Document](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/) and configure proper [FilterSet](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filterset.html) for the ModelViewSet and you'll be good to go.